# jQuery Form Validation being bypassed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my jQuery validation? It is not validating my form, rather, just ignoring the code resulting in no check of the inputs.

Form:

```
<form class="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="URL-to-complete-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<input class="form-name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></div>
<input class="form-email" type="text"placeholder="Email"></div>
<input style="background-color: #fc8f12;" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function validateForm()
{
    // Validate Name
    var title = $(".form-name").val();
    if (title=="" ||title=="Name" || title==null) { } else {
        alert("Please enter a name!");
    }

    // Validate Email
    var email = $(".form-email").val();
    if ((/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email)) || email=="" || email=="Email" || email==null) { } else {
        alert("Please enter a valid email");
    }
  return false;
}
```

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: there is certainly an error in your javascript which is letting the form to submit.. check your console and solve the errors..

Comment: Your function is always returning false

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're not doing anything to prevent the form from being submitted, because you have the "action=" line in the form... you're telling it to, on submit, both run the javascript function and submit the form.  You should have the javascript submit the form after it's validated. There are plenty of ways of doing it... probably the easiest is to make the submit button a type button instead of type submit, and then bind the validation and submission to the click of that button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are "intervening" the submit postback to do validation, shift your code so that is clear, remove the submit button from the form, do validation based on the button click and do your own form custom postback with the valid data:

```
 <form class="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="#">
        <input class="form-name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></div>
        <input class="form-email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button>Subscribe</button>

 $(function () {
            $('button').on('click', function (event) {
                validateForm();
            });

        });

        function validateForm() {
            // Validate Name
            var title = $(".form-name").val();
            if (!title) {
                alert("Please enter a name!");
                return false;
            }

            // Validate Email
            var email = $(".form-email").val();
            if (!email) {
                alert("Please an email address");
                return false;
            }

            if (!/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email)) {
                alert("Please enter a valid email");
                return false;
            }

            $.post('URL-to-complete-form', $("form").serialize(), function (data) {
                console.log('server call complete');
                console.log(data);
            });

        }
```

Here is a working jsFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/t8vQ2/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" ...
```

jQuery:

```
$("#form1").on("submit", function(){
  if($("input[name=firstName]").val() == ""){
    // errors here
    return false;
  }
});
```